# how to export many graphs (Highcharts) with only one click

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have many graphs in one page which I want to export them with one button "Export all", I don't know how, I know only how to do it for every graphs separetely. Thanx in Advance

Comment: this is question without any specifications, put some code or your work so we can help you

Comment: i need only the function name, or how to make it.I tried this one but it exported only the first $('#export').click(function() {
    Highcharts.exportCharts([chart1, chart2]);
}); , is there some other functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a loop

pseudo code:

```
$('#export').click(function() { 

    i = 0;

    while( charts are avaible ) {

        Highcharts.exportChart([ CHART i ]); });
        i++;

   }

}
```